# Simple JavaScript HTML table generator

Tags: javascript, html-table

This is JavaScript HTML table generator.

> ```
> Input (from textarea)
> <label> <content> //each line
> Order by <label>
> ```

I need to input the values like that:
[Input Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XljFn.png)
or

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
B 1
B 2
C 1
C 2
C 3
C 4
```

And the output should be :

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJjDw.png)

Here is the problem. I don't have ideas to finish my work, but i try my best to code.Can anyone help me?Please!!

```
function progress(){
    var txt = document.form.txt.value;
    var line = txt.split("\n"); // every line of context
    var line_num = line.length; // total line
    for (var i = 0; i<line_num; i++)
    {
        var seq = line[i].split(" "); //seq[0]: name of label, seq[1] : context
        // CODE START

        // CODE END
    }
    var out="<table>"; // if the value exist, using table to display

    // CODE START

    // CODE END
    out=out+"</table>"
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML=out; // display the result

}
```

And the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <title> HW3 </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="abc.js"></script>
        <style type = "text/css">
        table
        {
            width: 300px;           
            border:1px solid black;
            border-collapse : collapse;        
        }
        tr td
        {
            border:1px solid black;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <form name = "form" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
            <label><textarea name="txt" rows="20" cols = "40"></textarea></label>
            <br>
            <button type="submit" onclick = "javascript:progress()">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <p id= "out"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *Hint:* If you are building a table, you will need for sure an initial value before entering the loop and some appending to the value inside the loop. Start with writing the table manually for a small amount of values. Once you get the logical idea it will be much more simple. Good luck :)

Comment: @Frederik.L Do you have example for this ?

Comment: can you please create jsfiddle

Comment: @TC2Bee I tried something and added it as an alternative answer. Hope you like the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave it a try too. This approach should give you the big idea behind the dynamically created DOM elements. I think this is a more production-friendly version of the algorithm, given that only native JS is being used.

The main difference with my approach is that it works entirely with dynamic DOM Elements to build the table instead of static html markup. In some cases it can be easier to read and more flexible, especially if you want to work with tag attributes dynamically. I also managed to reduce the complexity by 1 level. Here's my try at it to make it simple and readable:

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    progress();
}, false);

function progress(){
    var txt = document.form.txt.value;
    var line = txt.split("\n"); // every line of context
    var line_num = line.length; // total line
    
    // Build label->content association
    var inputs = {};
    for (var i = 0; i<line_num; i++)
    {
        if (line[i] != "") {
            var seq = line[i].split(" "); //seq[0]: name of label, seq[1] : context
            var label = seq[0];
            var content = seq[1];
            if (inputs[label] === undefined) {
                inputs[label] = [content];
            } else {
                inputs[label].push(content);
            }
        }
    }
    
    // For a given MxN table output
    var M = Object.keys(inputs).length;
    var N = 0; // Unknown for now
    
    var tableElement = document.createElement("table");
    tableElement.id = "out";
    
    // Generate header
    var headerElement = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var label in inputs) {
        var tdElement = document.createElement("td");
        tdElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(label));
        headerElement.appendChild(tdElement);
        
        // calculate N dimension
        var contents = inputs[label].length;
        if (N < contents) {
            N = contents;
        }
    }
    tableElement.appendChild(headerElement);
    
    // Generate rows
    for (var i=0; i<N; i++) {
        var trElement = document.createElement("tr");
        for (var j=0; j<M; j++) {
            var tdElement = document.createElement("td");
            var label = Object.keys(inputs)[j];
            if (inputs[label].length > i) {
                var content = inputs[label][i];
                tdElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));
            }
            trElement.appendChild(tdElement);
        }
        tableElement.appendChild(trElement);
    }
    
    var out = document.getElementById('out');
    out.parentNode.removeChild(out);
    document.body.appendChild(tableElement); // display the result
}
```

```css
table {border-collapse:collapse;}
tr,td {border:solid 1px #000;}
td {width:100px;}
```

```html
<form name = "form" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
   <label>
<textarea name="txt" rows="20" cols = "40">
A 1
A 2
A 3
B 1
B 2
C 1
C 2
C 3
C 4
</textarea>
   </label>
   <br>
   <button id="btn" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<p id= "out"></p>
```

Hope this helps. Have a nice one!

For reference, you can see the [HTML Table Generator](https://www.htmltable.org).

Comment: Could you talk more details of your logic? I can't understand your algorithm like "Build label --> content association"

Comment: @TC2Bee The main idea here is to build a json object which has keys for each labels. Then, for each labels, if it doesn't exist, create an array at this position with only one content. Else, it means that the array already exists so you can push the content at the end of it. Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I have create sample based on your requirement.

Please check this code.

```js
function progress(){
  var txt = document.form.txt.value;
  var line = txt.split("\n"); // every line of context
  var line_num = line.length; // total line
  var uniqueValue = [];
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i<line_num; i++)
  {
    var seq = line[i].split(" "); //seq[0]: name of label, seq[1] : context
    if (uniqueValue.indexOf(seq[0]) == -1)
      {
        uniqueValue.push(seq[0]);
        values[uniqueValue.indexOf(seq[0])] = new Array();
      }
     values[uniqueValue.indexOf(seq[0])].push(seq[1]);
    }
    var maxLength = 0;
    var length = values.length;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
      if(values[i].length > maxLength)
        maxLength = values[i].length
    }
    if (length > 0)
    {
      var out = "<table>"; // if the value exist, using table to display
      for (var i = 0; i <= maxLength; i++)
      {
        out = out + "<tr>"
        for (var j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
          if(i==0)
          {
            out = out+ "<th>"+ uniqueValue[j] +"</th>";
          }
          else
          {
            if (values[j][i - 1])
              out = out + "<td>" + values[j][i - 1] + "</td>";
            else
              out = out + "<td></td>";
          }
      }
      out = out + "</tr>"
    }
    out = out + "</table>"
   }
  document.getElementById('out').innerHTML=out; // display the result
}
```

```css
table
        {
            width: 300px;           
            border:1px solid black;
            border-collapse : collapse;        
        }
        tr td, tr th
        {
            border:1px solid black;
        }
```

```html
<form name = "form" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
  <label><textarea name="txt" rows="20" cols = "40"></textarea></label>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" onclick = "javascript:progress()">Submit</button>
</form>
<p id= "out"></p>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: First I found the unique values and stored in uniqueValue variable. like A, B,C. Also I stored the equivalent value to multi dimension array. Using the multi dimension array, I have created the table.